# datatable with radio button always null pointer

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working with JSF and Primefaces and I am using a datatable with a single-selection radio button.

The code looks like this:

```
     <p:dataTable rendered="#{BeforBean.bol}" id="radioDT" var="per" 
      value="#{BeforBean.per}" paginator="true"  selection="#{BeforBean.select}" rowKey="#{per.nom}" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                Résulat de votre Recherche
            </f:facet>
            <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:2%;text-align:center"/>
            <p:column headerText="nom">
                  <h:outputText value="#{per.nom}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Prenom">
                   <h:outputText value="#{per.prenom}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="CIN">
                   <h:outputText value="#{per.CIN}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Poste">
                    <h:outputText value="#{per.poste}" />
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
```

and my bean:

```
    private List<personne> per = new ArrayList<personne>();
    private personne select;
```

The bean is viewscoped. I have all my getters and setters.

The problem is when I try to access the `personne` selected with the variable `select`, I always get null pointer.

Comment: a comment completely aside from the answer: your _personne_ class violates [naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) by starting with a lowercase letter. Even if you plan to fix this later, it's best to start with proper conventions.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your     `<p:datatable>` is inside an `<h:form>`.

Next, try adding the following inside your `<p:datatable>`:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{BeforBean.onRowSelect}"/>
```

Finally, on your BeforBean, create the following method:

```
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event){
  ...
  select = (Personne) event.getObject(); // your personne object is called select
  ...
}
```

Now you'll be able to choose your personne object! Remember to capitalize the first letter of your classes: Personne... Bonne chance!